# How to update Integer field which is inside the Children using MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have below Bson **string** Property **salary**  and update functionality was working fine.

```
public class Children
{
    [BsonElement("salary")]
    public string salary{ get; set; }
}

public class EmpInfoData
{
    public Children Children  {get;set;}
}

//Update working fine with string salary data type.
UpdateDefinition<EmpInfoData> update = Builders<EmpInfoData>.Update.Set( x => x.children[-1].salary, "2340");
```

Later salary field data type got changed to Integer. After changing i am getting error. how to update a Integer filed which is under children class?

```
public class Children
{
    [BsonElement("salary")]
    public int salary{ get; set; }
}
```

> Error at update statement
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'FiledDefinition-EmpInfoData,string-" because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Is this part correct `[BsonElement("order")]`? You really renamed the `salary` column in mongo to `order`?

Comment: @ntohl, I correct [BsonElement("salary")]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you changing the data type and wondering how to migrate them ? or just updating an integer field ? if the latter, you just replace the string `"2340"` to `2340`

Comment: @wan Bachtial, Yes I changed the string "2340" to 2340. Its not working for Integer datatype.  e.g.Set( x => x.children[-1].salary, 2340);

Comment: If you're migrating your data type from `string` to `int` than you have to do this first on the collection. The problem here is you have a `string` mapped data but you're trying to replace with `int`. See also [Handling Schema Changes](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/schema_changes/)